# how to create a service from my app for uninstalling my app and installing new app(upgrade)?

Tags: android, service, auto-update

I have an android app that I put update ability for it. In it,the app download new version .apk file from server if new version is available, and install the new. But the issue is : an existing package by the same name with a confilcting signature is already installed, while installing. Now I want create a service from my app that in it ,service remove current app, and install new version downloaded.How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

First, Why not just auto update through the store?
Second, if you want to self update you're gonna have to be a system app and have the install permission.

Make sure you signed the apk with the same creds as you did the apk waiting to be download in the server

Then, the best way i can think of is to use reflection to invoke the PackageManager's installPackage method with a Uri to your apk